# Error: falló la ejecución para tarea :packageDebug al compilar

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

Me está sucediendo un error un tanto raro al tratar de ejecutar desde la línea de comandos una aplicación hecha con Cordova. Al hacer un *build* de mi app con el siguiente comando:

```
cordova build -release
```

Obtengo que el proyecto compiló sin errores de ningún tipo, pero cuando voy a probar la app en un dispositivo (que primero compila en modo debug y luego instala), con el siguiente comando:

```
cordova run android
```

Recibo el siguiente error, falla el *build* y no se instala en el dispositivo:

> Execution failed for task ':packageDebug'.
>   > !zip.isFile()

El error también menciona que puedo usar el parámetro `--stacktrace` para obtener información adicional, pero realmente no proporciona mucho más que eso.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?

Comment: Alvaro que tal, mencionas que al ejecutar con --stacktrace no te muestra más información, probaste con un simple Clean y Rebuild, te sugiero también eliminar los folder /build  y probar nuevamente.

Comment: @Jorgesys pon eso como respuesta. Es lo que acabé haciendo (basándome en lo que encontré [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42801509/3695983)) y me funcionó.

Comment: cuando no me muestra nada con --stacktrace o --debug, solo elimino el folder /build o realizo un Clean a mi proyecto y creo que siempre es efectivo. @AlvaroMontoro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si al ejecutar con la opción `--stacktrace` no se muestra información con más detalle del error, puede ser suficiente con:

`Clean` > `Rebuild`

Personalmente elimino los folder `/build` que es algo similar y construyo nuevamente el proyecto.