# Error con plugin ionic

Tags: ionic3, plugin, android-notifications

Estoy tratando de generar notificaciones en mi app hecha en ionic.

Las notificaciones que quiero lograr hacer son **notificaciones locales**, no PUSH.

Para aprender a utilizarlas he creado una app vacía y luego, si todo funciona bien, lo pasaré a mi aplicación.

El plugin que utilizo es el siguiente: de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification

Para instalarlo he seguido los pasos que se han compartido aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43992746/7856247

Mi problema es que, si sigo esos pasos (trabajo con ionic 3) a la hora de probarlo en un dispositivo ni siquiera me ejecuta la app, me lanza una serie de excepciones.

Para probarlo en mi dispositivo lo hago con

> ionic cordova run android

Como he dicho, no lo ejecuta y no es porque entre en conflicto con otros plugin ya que lo estoy intentando hacer en una app vacía.

Los errores que me lanza son los siguientes:

> ...
>
> UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
>
> UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:generateDebugResources  UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:packageDebugResources
>
> UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:platformAttrExtractor UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:processDebugResources  UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>
> UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
>   :CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugBuild  UP-TO-DATE
>
> :app:compileDebugAidl  UP-TO-DATE
>
> :CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript
>
> UP-TO-DATE :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareLintJar
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResValues  UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugResources 
>   UP-TO-DATE
>
> :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
>
> UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugManifest  UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug  UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugResources
>   C:\Users\Usuario.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-28.0.0-alpha3.aar\40d806b4085ca0d6e9b2f0fa44f31b8b\res\values\values.xml:82:5-70:
>   AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>
> C:\Users\Usuario.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-28.0.0-alpha3.aar\40d806b4085ca0d6e9b2f0fa44f31b8b\res\values\values.xml:82:5-70:
>   AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
>
> C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\ionicProjects\prueba50\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:86:
>   error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>   C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\ionicProjects\prueba50\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:86:
>   error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found. error: failed linking
>   references.
>
> Failed to execute aapt
>
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute
>   aapt
>           at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
>   FAILED 25 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 24 up-to-date
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for
>   details
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
>           at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
>           ... 48 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for
>   details
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
>           at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:179)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           ... 1 more Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>           at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:454)
>           at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:411)
>           at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)
>           at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
>   > Failed to execute aapt
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 3s (node:10352) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
>   Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command
>   failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   C:\Users\Usuario.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-28.0.0-alpha3.aar\40d806b4085ca0d6e9b2f0fa44f31b8b\res\values\values.xml:82:5-70:
>   AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>
> C:\Users\Usuario.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-28.0.0-alpha3.aar\40d806b4085ca0d6e9b2f0fa44f31b8b\res\values\values.xml:82:5-70:
>   AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
>
> C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\ionicProjects\prueba50\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:86:
>   error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>   C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\ionicProjects\prueba50\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:86:
>   error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found. error: failed linking
>   references.
>
> Failed to execute aapt
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute
>   aapt
>           at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
>           at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>           at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>           at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
>           at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for
>   details
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
>           at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
>           ... 48 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for
>   details
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
>           at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:179)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           ... 1 more Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>           at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:454)
>           at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:411)
>           at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)
>           at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
>   > Failed to execute aapt
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 3s (node:10352) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning:
>   Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise
>   rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process
>   with a non-zero exit code.
>
> [OK] Your app has been deployed.
>        Did you know you can live-reload changes from your app with --livereload?

A la hora de instalar el plugin no me da ningún error, no veo si hay alguna incompatibilidad o que pasa pero no deja ejecutarlo.

Comment: Tuve el [mismo problema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/172171/250) hace unos días. Lo resolví haciendo un clean y luego build de nuevo. Luego me salió otro error más concreto (un plugin usaba funciones obsoletas), actualicé el plugin y todo solucionado. Prueba eso a ver si te funciona.

Comment: Lo probaré y comento el resultado, de momento lo que he hecho ha sido utilizar este otro plugin: https://medium.com/@tfernandez_99761/notificaciones-en-ionic-8f13e8f4b840 y me ha funcionado

Comment: ¿Cómo instalaste el plugin? (el que da fallo)

Comment: el que me falló con ionic cordova plugin add de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification y después npm install --save @ionic-native/local-notifications

Comment: La cosa es que encontré dos versiones de ese plugin: [la versión que instalaste](https://www.npmjs.com/package/de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification) (que parece estar desactualizada porque sólo llega a la 0.85 y salió hace más de un año) y [otra versión en GitHub](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) (que parece fue renombrada y actualizada hace apenas un par de meses, al menos la beta 3). Prueba a instalar siguiendo las instrucciones de github `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-local-notification` y puede que así el problema se solucione.

Comment: Si, como te he dicho, ese plugin me ha funcionado bien, al lanzar la última versión han debido arreglar ciertas incompatibilidades que tenía. Gracias